# Laravel 5.4 Auth issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am attempting to get *basic* authentication working on a fresh Laravel installation, and am failing miserably.  I have read the Laracasts and poured over S.O. in attempts to find my shortcomings to no avail.  Hence I am here.

At the top of my login.blade.php I have a simple `if` statement.  Just checking if the user is logged in .. I am using the base Laravel `login.blade.php` that is created during `make:auth` simply with this if statement up top.

```
@if (Auth::check())
    The user is logged in...
@else
    The user is not logged in
@endif
```

Inside of `App/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` is very simple:

```
<?php

namespace Y3\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Y3\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

So I am attempting to redirect to `/home` if they are logged in and I have a logout override in there that just logs them out and redirects them back to `/login` --  This is facilitated in `web.php` where I added this to the bottom:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('logout', '\Y3\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

**MY ISSUE**

The user never gets "logged in" --  They are never redirected to the `home` blade *and* my `if statement` always displays `The user is not logged in`.  I can tell the the Auth is doing **something** because if I type the wrong username or password -- it fails with `These credentials do not match our records.`  Also the `/logout` works (I think) because it does redirect to the `/login` blade.

I don't see any syntactical errors, so I think my logic is flawed .. Does anyone see any glaring mistakes with the way I am attempting this?

Comment: How did you create the auth logic? By hand or did you use the auth scaffold (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authentication-quickstart).

Comment: I did use `php artisan make:auth` as I just need basic authentication .. So I am using all of Laravel's "built in" authentication

Comment: By basic do you mean "HTTP Basic" or just basic like simple? The first can be used without the need for the auth scaffolding: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#http-basic-authentication

Comment: By basic I mean "simple"  sorry for the confusion --  Using all the built in Laravel routes, auth and functionality .. I just need simple authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by:

**1)** A fresh install of Laravel.

**2)** I then changed the name-space. `php artisan app:name Y3`

**3)** After namespace change, I checked `composer.json` to ensure the namespace change was successful, and I did a `composer dump-autoload` for good measure.

**4)** After testing the install.  I then did the `php artisan make:auth`

**5)** In the users migration file that was created, I changed the table name from users to my desired table name.

**6)** I then went to `/config/auth.php` and changed **this:**

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

      //   'users' => [
      //       'driver' => 'database',
      //       'table' => 'users',
      //   ],
    ],
```

**To this:**

```
'providers' => [
      //  'users' => [
      //      'driver' => 'eloquent',
      //      'model' => App\User::class,
      //  ],

         'users' => [
             'driver' => 'database',
             'table' => 'my_new_table_name',
         ],
    ],
```

7) I then ran `php artisan migrate`

I successfully changed namespace, changed name of `auth` table in the database, and kept `Auth` working all the while -- Thanks to all who devoted time to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your routes are out of `web` middleware

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'web'],function () {
    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('logout', '\Y3\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
});
```

Secondly don't forget to clear your browser cookies and caches

Hope this helps

Comment: I get the same result .. I put in my credentials, and it just redirects back to `http://mywebsite.com/login` and still displays that `This user is not logged in`  Am I checking login status correctly in my login blade (the if statement)?

Comment: @Zak try it in cognito

Comment: I always do ;) --

Comment: btw -- The redirect from `/home` to `/login` works -- I failed to mention that in the OP -- Just the actual logging in doesn't work

Comment: First of all, as you can see in the `__construct()` method, every method in the LoginController.php file **except** `logout()` is for `guests`. Which means your login method can not be called by authenticated uses. So you will never see **The user is logged in...** in your login.blade.php file because it is for guests only and an authenticated user is not a guest. Second; can you copy the same if else statement from login.blade.php to home.blade.php to see if your user is logged in ?

Comment: I copied that if statement to the welcome blade (because home always redirects to login blade) It still says user is not logged in.

Comment: In addition I added - `print_r(Auth::user());`   nada

Answer (score 0):

Change your `logout` method to the following:

```
/**
 * Logout, Clear Session, and Return.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function logout()
{
    $user = /Auth::user();
    Log::info('User Logged Out. ', [$user]);
    /Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();
    return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
}
```

And update the constructor in as well

```
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

Any errors in the `laravel.log` file?

Ok. so here is what an out the box working `web.php` with auth looks like for L5.6:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Here is what the basic `LoginController.php` will look like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Here is what `login.blade.php` should look like out the box:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                    {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Once logged in it will redirect you to `home.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    You are logged in!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And an out the box `app.blade.php` that those blades extend from:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have done what you requested ..  Still just refreshing the login page ... Also no errors in the laravel.log .. I emptied the log and attempted the login 5 times with 0 errors logged ..

Comment: Just a quick observation on your question is that some of the conditional logic `@if` code in `login.blade.php` will not be seen. The blade view `login.blade.php` can only be seen by un-authenticated users.

Comment: Hey at least we got somewhere .. I copied all of your (out of the box) code .. When I hit the Login button, I now get "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again."

Comment: I figured out the Expired page .. I replaced `@csrf` with `{{ csrf_field() }}` in the login blade -- Still redirecting to login blade with no logging in  ... If I go directly to /home it redirects me to /login

Comment: Here is a factory instance I put together for you: https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel.local

Comment: I downloaded the factory and it works fine ..  I copy all the auth files over to my production and the same issue of redirecting to `/login`.  I have a question --  I changed the namespace on my application from `App` to `Y3` -- Could this have affected things?

Comment: If you did not define the change in the `composer.json` file it will. https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel.local/blob/master/composer.json#L27

Comment: I defined it in `composer.json` and I did a `composer dump-autoload`